# Suppress specific analysis error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, roslyn

I'm implemented `ICompileModule`, which allow using generic attributes. It works fine (Build successful), but **Visual Studio** mark this code as error (at analysis step).

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

[image: Error 3]

How i can hide/suppress these errors? May be using Visual Stuido/ReSharper plugin?

Comment: Do you understand the message *"A generic type cannot derive from 'Attribute' because it is an attribute class"*? What makes you think such an error can be suppressed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C# forbid generic attribute types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294216/why-does-c-sharp-forbid-generic-attribute-types)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, i understand the message and i'm implemented module, which allow using generic attributes (`========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Any way to suppress compiler errors similar to suppressing warning messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998321/c-any-way-to-suppress-compiler-errors-similar-to-suppressing-warning-messages)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, i do not want suppress compiler error, because at compilation step all fine. I need suppress/hide analysis error.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not the answer to this particular question, but it may help others who came here via the question's title.*

Some errors are created by **Roslyn Analyzers** that can be toggled:

Right-click on project's References > Analyzers , "Open Active Rule Set"
[image: first step]

Then toggle the error in question

[image: second step]

Unfortunately for @maxswitcher, the error in question is not handled by Roslyn Analyzers.